# Perforce corrupting .sql files when adding

Tags: sql-server, perforce, corruption

This is a weird one, and it has happened to me twice now, so its not just some freak incident.

I wanted to add a new `.sql` file to my project.

I opened up SQL Management Studio 2012, wrote my script, and saved it.

I opened Helix, switched to my workspace, right clicked the file, clicked "Mark for Add"

Perforce marked that file as type `text+k`

Right clicked on the file, clicked "Submit", filled out my commit message, and clicked "Submit"

I go back to my file, and it looks like this:

[image]

(I was unable to paste the text, as StackOverflow thought it was spam)

I thought that at first it was just adding junk in between lines, but the first few lines should read:

```
USE TestDatabase
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

Which means that my data is actually being corrupted somehow.

How can I stop this from happening? Bonus points if you can tell me how to recover this file that I spent a good amount of time on.

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3444

Comment: @DavidTansey I hadn't until now. That's basically what I was looking for. Now I need to go vent about how stupid this is while re-writing my script. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to work around by telling SSMS that you want to use ANSI rather than UNICODE.  Try the following to see if it resolves your issue:  SSMS `Tools` | `Options` | `Environments` | `International Settings` and then change the Language from _English_ to _Same as Microsoft Windows_.  Please let us know the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a file encoding problem.  SSMS 2012, being a Microsoft product, will default to UTF-16 encoding.  Many applications assume all text files are going to be UTF-8 now since it's the de facto (and often de jure) web encoding.

You can tell SSMS 2012 to save a file as UTF-8.

1. In SSMS, go File > Save As...
2. Enter the desired file name.
3. On the Save button, click the down arrow and select "Save with Encoding...".
4. Select "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" to save as UTF-8 with a byte order mark.
5. Select the proper line endings.  Most systems work with Windows, but some will want Unix line endings.

If UTF-8 does not work or if your application doesn't like the byte order mark, you can try something like "US-ASCII - Codepage 20127" or "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252."  The latter is what is often known as "ANSI".  US-ASCII is only going to work if you have any characters other than those in the original 256 ASCII table, so you'd lose any diacritical marks.  However, if everything you use is in common English it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

> Perforce marked that file as type text+k

Perforce never defaults files to `+k` on its own.  Perforce also usually detects UTF-16 files as such (or at least as binary).  I'm guessing your admin has a `typemap` entry that looks something like:

```
text+k //....sql
```

or maybe even:

```
text+k //some/path/...
```

This is abominable because, as you've learned, forcing something that is not ASCII to a `text` type can mangle it.  Tell your admin to replace `text+k` with simply `+k` so that it at least won't override the base filetype.

They may also want to rethink enabling keyword expansion by default on a path that can potentially include non-ASCII files -- keyword expansion works in some binary formats but others might not appreciate it, and it's also a performance hit because files need to be "refreshed" after every submit to make sure that any keywords present are re-expanded.  I always recommend being more specific with the `+k` option and enabling it on a file-by-file basis (i.e. the user that adds the $Keyword$ to the file should add the `+k` to the filetype at that time) rather than using typemap.